# What version of mongodb to choose? thinking about filtering

Tags: mongodb

I need to migrate a DB from postgress to MongoDB.

The fact is that we used many queries to filter the data, such as searching a range of dates, or records that had some string of characters, perform arithmetic operations etc ...

I know that the newer version is generally preferable, but I would like to know your opinion since I am not an expert in mongoDB.

regards

Comment: newer is the best, definitively : the way to query your data didn't change, except new aggregation framework stages, and last version includes ACID multi-document transactions, which can be very helpful in case of migration.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, it will be the most recent version. I heard about the multi-document ACID, sounds so good

Answer (score 1):

If you move from Postgress to MongoDB, best if you use MongoDB latest version.
After MongoDB 3.2 default search engine is write tiger. Older MongoDB versions supported MMAPv1. Based on search engine behavior of MongoDB behavior changing. Do research on it.

[image]